# Swift Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Session found

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Session found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Session may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

I am currently developing a SwiftUI application that is using Firebase for Authentication. If a user is not logged in, I want to take them to the login page and if they are logged in I would like them to go to the correct application views. This takes form of a WindowGroup with a few tabs.

Since I have users I have the concept of a Session Store that keeps track of the current users session. Fairly simple class.

```
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    @Published var signedIn = false
    
    var isSignedIn: Bool {
        return auth.currentUser != nil
    }
    
    func login(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] res, err in
            guard res != nil, err == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func register(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] res, err in
            guard res != nil, err == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While trying to run my application, I get the following error.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Session found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Session may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

```
struct app: App {
    @State var show = true
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color("Shallow"))
    }
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: Session

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if session.signedIn {
                TabView {
                    NavigationView {
                        DiscoverView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("discover")
                        Text("Discover")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        CollectorView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("collection")
                        Text("Liquor")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        BottlesView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("store")
                        Text("Recipes")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        ListsView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("lists")
                        Text("Lists")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        ProfileView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("profile")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }
                }
                .accentColor(Color("Rye"))
                
            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I felt this might have something to do with needing to add `.environmentObject` to each individual view in my window group. That yielded the same result. I have also tried adding this environment Object to the window group directly with no such luck. Does anybody have any ideas on what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because you have not instantiated a Session() before you pass it in. Try something like this:

```
@main
struct app: App {
    @State var show = true
    @StateObject var session = Session()  // <--- here
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color("Shallow"))
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if session.signedIn {
                TabView {
                    NavigationView {
                        DiscoverView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("discover")
                        Text("Discover")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        CollectorView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("collection")
                        Text("Liquor")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        BottlesView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("store")
                        Text("Recipes")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        ListsView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("lists")
                        Text("Lists")
                    }
                    NavigationView {
                        ProfileView()
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("profile")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }
                }
                .environmentObject(session)  // <--- here
                .accentColor(Color("Rye"))
                
            } else {
                LoginView()
                  .environmentObject(session) // <-- if you use it in this class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in your DiscoverView(), CollectorView() etc... add

```
@EnvironmentObject var session: Session
```